# Как поставить текст перед данными, выводимыми из БД в Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Т.е чтобы на выходе перед цифрой, означающей ID выводился текст "ID" у Специальности "Специальность" и тд, гугл молчит...

```
<ListBox x:Name="studentList" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.523,0.501" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="12" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ФИО}" FontSize="12" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Специальность}" FontSize="12" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Группа}" FontSize="12" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Средний_Балл}" FontSize="12" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Проблема то какие? Этот кусок хамл ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: Нужно что бы на выходе перед цифрой, означающей ID выводился текст "ID" у Специальности "Специальность" и тд, возможно ли это в самом xaml прописать?

Comment: `{Binding ID, StringFormat=ID: {0}}`?

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если надо добавить "приписку" к тексту на чистом XAML, то это можно сделать по сути двумя способами:

1. StringFormat.
   Суть данного способа в том, что вы в момент привязки задаете нужный вид текста и даже если вы его сотрете например в `TextBox`, он автоматически будет добавлен.

Пример:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, StringFormat=Какой то текст: {0}}" />
```

[image: Result 1]

2. Воспользоваться вложенностью элементов.
   XAML хорош тем, что почти каждый объект может иметь уйму других объектов внутри себя. Мы без труда можем вложить например в `TextBlock` два `Run` с нужным нам текстом.

Пример:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Какой то текст:"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Test}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

[image: Result 2]

Это по сути основные способы добавления текста на чистом XAML. Все другие способы будут затрагивать C# код (конвертеры, `ToString` и уйма др.).